How can I validate the SOAP Security Header using Spring Boot 3 & Spring WS Security
I have recently upgraded my Spring Boot SOAP Web Services Project to Spring Boot v3.2.3.
I need to validate the SOAP Security Header against an external system making a REST call.
I have gone through the sample example code at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-sample, this assumes the password is loaded from an external source and then it is compared against the SOAP UserToken header.
In my application we do not store the passwords/secrets for the user we must validate the password against an external source which is a RestEnd point.
How can I using the Security model for Sprint Boot 3 extract the username and password and validate this against an external system?
I would like to use the current security ws framework as this validates the nonce and timestamps in the header. I just need a way of obtaining the SOAP UserName and Password that is set in the Header.
I used the sample code provided in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples but this does not work for me as it is setting the password when the loadUserDetails method is invoked. This assumes it is taking the password from the database.
I need to validate username/password in the SOAP header itself against a third party system.

Please can someone help :)

At the moment I have resorted to implementing my own Soap Interceptor but this is not the best way forward. The username is always retrieval from the callback but I also need the password. I dont want to set this on the callback this should already be set from the SOAP Security Header.
